# AEM: Component Action Toolbar: Blank style list is visble

Tags: adobe, aem

We have a component that has a child component, within that, there is another child (child-2) component added. When in author ui, child-2 component does have style icon (in component action toolbar); however clicking on that renders a blank list.

If that child-2 component is added as independent component style icon as well as list (when clicked on) is also visible (with all styles variation as defined in policy).

We tried various ways to debug it but can not. Can anyone please help us here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AEM style system works by defining the styles in the policies. These policies should use the exact path where the component can potentially be placed.
Example: If the component's path is
*/apps/project/components/content/myheader* then the policy will be defined at path similar to below
*/conf/project/settings/wcm/policies/project/components/content/myheader/policy_xxx*.

But this policy definition will be used in a path in a template where you would use your component. For example if your template name is templateA and the name of the responsivegrid where your component **myheader** will be placed is headerGrid then myheader's policy will be used here:
*/conf/project/settings/wcm/templates/templateA/policies/jcr:content/headerGrid/project/components/content/myheader <cq:policy property>*.

The styles defined in policy will then only be visible in the above responsive grid (parsys in old language). To allow this styles in any other path, in your temlate create the path as required and use the policy there.

Following the above example, if you want your stlyes to be available in a componentA in the TemplateA where componentA is placed in bodyGrid then use the policy here:

*/conf/project/settings/wcm/templates/templateA/policies/jcr:content/bodyGrid/componentA/project/components/content/myheader <cq:policy property>.*

This should resolve your problem as tested in my system. Unfortunately there is no sandbox public to show you an example.